# MVC6 Can't find app.UseStaticFiles() in Startup

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am playing around the new ASPNET 5 beta using the latest version of Visual Studio Code (v0.3). I don't want to put the VS2015 RC on my work machine. I have a barebones (Hello World) MVC6 app which I've gotten running after figuring out the basics of the dn* command line tools.

Now I want to serve a static file. I've added Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles to my project.json file and restored the packages.

My project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot"
    ],
    "packExclude": [
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "Kestrel": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:8080",
        "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:8080"
    },
    "frameworks": {
         "dnx451": { },
         "dnxcore50": { }
    }
}
```

My Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

namespace EmailViewer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {            
            app.UseErrorPage();
            app.UseStaticFiles(); 
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            app.UseWelcomePage(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I include app.UseStaticFiles() at which point I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EmailViewer' or one of its dependencies. General Exception (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131500)
File name: 'EmailViewer' ---> Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationException: C:\src\fx5\EmailViewer\Startup.cs(16,13): error CS7069: Reference to type 'IApplicationBuilder' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http', but it could not be found
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynProjectReference.Load(IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at dnx.host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at dnx.host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName name, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadAssemblyImpl(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.TryLoadAssembly(LoadContext context, AssemblyName assemblyName, Assembly& assembly)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(AssemblyName assemblyRef)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Startup.StartupLoader.FindStartupType(String startupAssemblyName, IList`1 diagnosticMessages)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureStartup()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Internal.HostingEngine.Start()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host, String applicationName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at dnx.host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args, IRuntimeEnvironment env)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args)
   at dnx.host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args)


Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynCompilationException: C:\src\fx5\EmailViewer\Startup.cs(16,13): error CS7069: Reference to type 'IApplicationBuilder' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http', but it could not be found
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynProjectReference.Load(IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName, IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at dnx.host.LoaderContainer.Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at dnx.host.DefaultLoadContext.LoadAssembly(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoaderCache.GetOrAdd(AssemblyName name, Func`2 factory)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.LoadAssemblyImpl(AssemblyName assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.TryLoadAssembly(LoadContext context, AssemblyName assemblyName, Assembly& assembly)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.LoadContext.ResolveAssembly(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

I've tried using these versions:

- 1.0.0-beta4
- 1.0.0-beta6-12114

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: VS 2015 RC has a Go Live license - it means it's supported for production work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In asp.net MVC6 rc1,

add following line into project.json's 'dependencies' section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
```

Answer (score 8):

In ASP.NET MVC6 RC2, add the following line into the project.json "dependencies" section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
```

Answer (score 7):

In beta6/beta5, it has been changed as follows :

```
 //app.UseStaticFiles();
 app.UseMiddleware<StaticFileMiddleware>(new StaticFileOptions());
```

Also upgrading from beta4 to beta5 is not a easiest thing, but it is possible..

Comment: Ok that worked, but now it can't load the PathString type. `System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http.PathString' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Http, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

Comment: @GwendolynGoetz, Please ensure that you have included necessary directives (in vs2015, Ctrl+. shows potential fixes). If my solution worked please mark this solution as answer.

Comment: there is a blog written by Miguel Alho, http://www.miguelalho.pt/upgrading-vnext-mvc6-apps-from-beta4-to-beta5/  which sets u in right path.

Comment: This only seems supported by beta5 and not beta6. Struggling to serve static files! Any ideas?

Comment: @davenewza.. It is working in beta7 but you have to refer the Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles ..  I didn't tested in beta6 but i think that it should work in beta6 also.

Comment: With Beta8 it is app.UseStaticFiles() again

Comment: Final version this is as you described and dependency is   "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0".

Answer (score 6):

If your .net Core app uses csproj add the following line:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
```

Or run the command @Steve listed:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
```

Comment: Exactly. There *is no* package.json file to modify anymore, and there's no "StaticFileMiddleware" middleware package.  This stuff (and Angular 2 & 4) are changing so damn fast, most of the StackOverflow responses are out-of-date...

Answer (score 5):

**For .net core visual studio code**

open terminal windows or command prompt in the project root folder and install the 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles package

dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles

**For Visual studio**

add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles package using nuget

Worked for me

Comment: Worked for me on a Mac

Answer (score 4):

Change, change, ..., even more recent:

Add to `project.json` in "dependencies" section:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

In Startup.cs, you can now use

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Comment: While this is correct (as of 2017), Note: project.json is deprecated. You need to add the references into your csproj instead.

Answer (score 3):

For VS 2017, I installed using NuGet manager but `StaticFiles` was still not accessible. I even removed and re-added by editing the .csproj file (XML replacement of JSON) but I was still unable to access. I eventually fixed the issue by saving the project and restarting VS 2017.

Comment: I found that I didn't have to restart VS 2017, but I could simply close the project and bring it up again.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to install static files library. Open up nuget package and search static files, you will find microsoft.owin.staticfiles install it and it will work.I had the same problem and after installing it worked great.